# How to save <IPython.core.display.Image object> as png file

Tags: python, data-visualization, visualization, graphviz, pydot

When I run this code it's showing <IPython.core.display.Image object>  but I need to save the file as png on my computer, how to do this

This is the code to create Unix Directory Structure Using Graphviz

```
    import pydot
    import os
    from IPython.display import Image, display

    rootdir = "/home/niranjan/Pictures/proj1"
    G = pydot.Dot(graph_type="digraph")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for subdir in dirs:
            node = pydot.Node(subdir,style="filled",fillcolor="green")
            G.add_node(node)
            edge = pydot.Edge(root.split("/")[-1],subdir)
            G.add_edge(edge)

    for file in files:
        node = pydot.Node(file,style="filled",fillcolor="yellow")
        G.add_node(node)
        edge = pydot.Edge(root.split("/")[-1],file)
        G.add_edge(edge)



    im = Image(G.create_png())
    display(im)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `G.write_png("file.png")`
You can also save the file as jpeg or other formats available.